# Postgresql Range data types (odd , even , mix) ranges

Tags: postgresql, range, range-types

Wondering if there is any option of using build in range data types to create ranges odd or even or mixed something like range(lower-bound,upper-bound, step) but with Built-in Range Types so i can use  the range operators.

Right now im building arrays like below but would like to understand if somehow the built in range types can hold this sort of ranges under the wood.

```
SELECT
ARRAY (SELECT arr FROM 
        generate_series(1, 10, CASE WHEN 1 in (1,2) THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) arr
        ) as data_range;
```

data_range -> "{1,3,5,7,9}"

Comment: That's not a range, right? A range contains *all* values between the endpoints.

Comment: i dont exactly aggree with that , you could argue its not a sequential range ... but thats my view myabe im wrong

Comment: Which range operators do you want, exactly? Have you looked at the [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html#INTARRAY-OP-TABLE) module?

Comment: No i have not seen the intarray ... i see interest in overlap ( && ) , intersection ( *  ) , diference ( - )

Comment: Documentation mentions that you can create your own range with custom step, but I don't see any hint on how to do that. So it seems like it is possible, just not clear how.